# angular 2 pass variable from injectable to component

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, interceptor

I wrote an http interceptor in order to catch all 5xx errors from server. The idea is that in app.component.html I have component (bad-response) which must be displayed if there is an 5xx error. In an interceptor I can check whether there is an error. But how can I pass this information to "bad-response" component?

I've tried to create another service, which will be injected in component for getting variable value and in interceptor for setting it, but no luck.

**app.component.html**

```
<top-nav></top-nav>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>

<bad-response></bad-response> //need to pass info about 5xx error here
```

**interceptor.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class InterceptedHttp extends Http {
  constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
   super(backend, defaultOptions);
  }

  request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    return super.request(url, options);
  }

  get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    super.get(url, this.getRequestOptionArgs(options)).subscribe((res: Response) => {
     // here I can get to response status code via res.status
   });
   return super.get(url, this.getRequestOptionArgs(options));
  }

  ...other code
}
```

**bad-response.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="isBadResponse">
  Sorry, there are connection problems
</div>
```

**bad-response.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'bad-response',
  templateUrl: './bad-response.component.html'
})

export class BadResponseComponent implements OnInit {

  isBadResponse: boolean;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that it could be done via another service which connects component and injectable and uses **static** property

Comment: Could you please provide where you found that?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest just making your `BadResponseComponent` take an input variable from the parent component and just do what you like with that from there on.

You can achieve that by using the `@Input` decorator.

An example of your `BadResponseComponent` would look something like this:

```
import {Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'bad-response',
  templateUrl: './bad-response.component.html'
})

export class BadResponseComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() isBadResponse: boolean;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

In this case the parent component where you are using the `BadResponseComponent` will provide the `isBadResponse` boolean and you can do what you like with it afterwards.

[COMPONENT INTERACTION](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html) - This is a good source to learn more about component interaction.

Comment: ok, but this also means that I need somehow pass _isBadResponse_ variable value to parent component from interceptor

Comment: @A.Pipchenko, why not just make the call in the parent component, use the interceptor(in the parent component) to check if there is a 5xx error there and pass a boolean to the bad response component indicating that it's a bad response?